# Cache API troubleshooting

Tags: 7, caching

I'm trying to cache an object returned after a 3rd party API call via HTTP. The API charges based on calls, so I'm trying to cache the information returned for some period of time.

However I don't seem to be able to get cache_set() to ever store anything. I've enabled "Cache pages for anonymous users" and "Cache blocks" in the performance configuration, as I read somewhere that the cache API may depend on those being set.

I'm using code inside a function called in hook_block_view():

> $cache_key = 'custom_module'.$index;
>
> $conditions = cache_get($cache_key);
>
> if (!$conditions) {
>      $conditions = API_CALL($index);
>      cache_set($cache_key, $conditions, 'cache',  REQUEST_TIME  + (60 * 10)); //stores in cache table and expires after 10 minutes
>   }

However this still results in an API call per page load with testing from a logged out browser.
I added some minimal test code:

> cache_set('testing','foo','cache',CACHE_PERMANENT);
>   var_dump(cache_get('testing'));

And the output is "bool(false)".

Looking in the database shows the 'cache' table is empty.

I'm about to start digging through the function calls being cache_set() to see what is happening, and intend to report back what I find. However if this is a common problem perhaps someone already has an answer?

Comment: Just copy/pasted your code into /devel/php and `cache_get('testing')->data == 'foo'` as expected. Your cache table shouldn't be empty (unless you're not using db cache) so it might suggest you have a custom/contrib module invalidating the cache on every page load

Comment: Yep - just had a forehead slap moment. Earlier in the piece I had problems with excess caching, and had configured up "DrupalFakeCache".
Had to debug down into the cache_set function to realise it wasn't calling the default cache implementation before I remembered!

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, and I had configured up the DrupalFakeCache earlier in development to prevent caching. Clearly this results in no caching.